# VBA Zoom Level Setting

Tags: vba, excel

What VBA command can I use to set a standard zoom level for all excel worksheets, that also allows me to increase/decrease the zoom level by 10% by clicking?

FYI: I am creating two buttons (zoom in and zoom out) in excel that allows user to adjust zoom settings from title page of document - will adjust entire workbook.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I have tested this and it works but I still need to have a starting
>   zoom level of 75 or something. How can I adjust with that as the
>   starting point? – Eric Walker Oct 5 at 20:44

you can use

```
Public Sub Auto_Open()
    ActiveWindow.zoom = 75
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is untested but should give you the idea... Link your buttons to the DecreaseZoom and IncreaseZoom subroutines.

```
Public ZoomSetting As Integer

Sub DecreaseZoom  
    If ZoomSetting = 0 Then
        ZoomSetting = 100
    End If
    If ZoomSetting > 10 Then
        ZoomSetting = ZoomSetting - 10
        SetZoom
    End If
End Sub

Sub IncreaseZoom
    If ZoomSetting = 0 Then
        ZoomSetting = 100
    End If
    If ZoomSetting < 400 Then
        ZoomSetting = ZoomSetting + 10
        SetZoom
    End If
End Sub

Sub SetZoom()
    Dim CurrentWS As Worksheet, TempWS As Worksheet
    CurrentWS = ActiveWorksheet
    For Each TempWS In Worksheets
        TempWS.Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = ZoomLevel
    Next
    CurrentWS.Select
End Sub
```

FYI, if you select all worksheets in your workbook using the tabs you can then set the zoom and it will apply to all worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActiveWindow.Zoom`.

```
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 10
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 120
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 110
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Activewindow.zoom = activewindow.zoom -10` to zoom out, and `Activewindow.zoom = activewindow.zoom +10` to zoom in.

Comment: I have tested this and it works but I still need to have a starting zoom level of 75 or something. How can I adjust with that as the starting point?